# Calculating what proportion of a variable is in a given discrete state on a given date in an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr

I have a dataframe of time series data which is tracking the status of several species as discrete states. I want to calculate what proportion of each species is in each state for each day in the time series.

So my data is something like this:

```
example.df <- data.frame(date = rep(seq(ymd("2022-3-6"), ymd("2022-3-8"), by = "days"),
                          each = 8),
               species = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 4),
               state = sample(0:2, replace = TRUE, size = 24))

print(example.df)

             date species state
1  2022-03-06       a     0
2  2022-03-06       a     2
3  2022-03-06       a     1
4  2022-03-06       a     0
5  2022-03-06       b     2
6  2022-03-06       b     1
7  2022-03-06       b     0
8  2022-03-06       b     1
9  2022-03-07       a     0
10 2022-03-07       a     1
11 2022-03-07       a     0
12 2022-03-07       a     0
13 2022-03-07       b     1
14 2022-03-07       b     1
15 2022-03-07       b     1
16 2022-03-07       b     2
17 2022-03-08       a     1
18 2022-03-08       a     0
19 2022-03-08       a     1
20 2022-03-08       a     1
21 2022-03-08       b     1
22 2022-03-08       b     2
23 2022-03-08       b     2
24 2022-03-08       b     2
```

I want to produce something like this:

```
            date species proportion.0 proportion.1 proportion.2
1 2022-03-06       a         0.25         0.25         0.50
2 2022-03-06       b         0.25         0.50         0.25
3 2022-03-07       a         0.25         0.50         0.25
4 2022-03-07       b         0.25         0.50         0.25
5 2022-03-08       a         0.00         1.00         0.00
6 2022-03-08       b         0.00         0.75         0.25
```

I've been trying to do this in dplyr using group_by() and summarise() but I cannot figure out a generic term to get the proportion for every day/ species combination. Any help would be greatly appreciated, staying inside the tidyverse if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Could do something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

example.df |>
  count(date, species, state) |>
  group_by(date, species) |>
  mutate(f = n/sum(n),
         state = paste0("proportion.", state)) |>
  select(-n) |>
  ungroup()|>
  pivot_wider(names_from = state, values_from = f, values_fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   date       species proportion.0 proportion.1 proportion.2
#>   <date>     <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 2022-03-06 a               0.25         0.5          0.25
#> 2 2022-03-06 b               0.25         0.5          0.25
#> 3 2022-03-07 a               0.75         0            0.25
#> 4 2022-03-07 b               0.5          0.25         0.25
#> 5 2022-03-08 a               0.5          0            0.5 
#> 6 2022-03-08 b               0.5          0            0.5
```

First we `count` the number of species in each state in each day. Then we calculate the proportion of each state (i.e., `f`) for each date and species. Lastly, we `pivot_wider` to go from long to wide format.

EDIT:

I thought of another option:

```r
example.df |>
  mutate(v = 1) |>
  pivot_wider(names_prefix = "proportion.", 
              names_from = state, 
              values_from = v,
              values_fn = list(v = sum),
              values_fill = 0) |>
  (\(d) mutate(d, across(contains("proportion."), \(x) x/rowSums(d[,3:5]))))()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   date       species proportion.1 proportion.0 proportion.2
#>   <date>     <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 2022-03-06 a               0.75         0.25         0   
#> 2 2022-03-06 b               0.25         0.25         0.5 
#> 3 2022-03-07 a               0.25         0.25         0.5 
#> 4 2022-03-07 b               0.5          0.5          0   
#> 5 2022-03-08 a               0.25         0.5          0.25
#> 6 2022-03-08 b               0            0            1
```

Here we set up a placeholder column called `v`, then we pivot wider and calculate the number of states per species per date. Then we calculate the proportions using `rowSums`.